# How do I uninstall this buildpack in Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, buildpack

I installed [`heroku-buildpack-php-tyler`](https://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler) on my Heroku app a few days ago, and it all seemed to work fine. I installed it by running the following command:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler.git
```

However I now want to remove it. I tried using the following command:

```
heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler.git
```

But it returns the following error message:

> Unsetting BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler.git and restarting hnf-heroku... failed
>
> !    Resource not found`

Because PHP isn't officially supported by Heroku, there's not much documentation about this. So how do I uninstall this buildpack?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL
```

Comment: hey thanks, I already got the answer from somewhere else, but this works (for those coming from Google, it essentially resets the Buildpack back to the default state). Thanks though! :)

Comment: `heroku buildpacks:remove BUILDPACK_URL --app [APP_NAME]` is the correct one.

Answer (score 31):

In the current version of `heroku` (v3.1.0 as of this writing) you can use `heroku buildpacks:remove [BUILDPACK_URL]`

Typing `heroku buildpacks help` lists the available commands:

```
  buildpacks:add BUILDPACK_URL       #  add new app buildpack, inserting into list of buildpacks if neccessary
  buildpacks:clear                   #  clear all buildpacks set on the app
  buildpacks:remove [BUILDPACK_URL]  #  remove a buildpack set on the app
  buildpacks:set BUILDPACK_URL       #  set new app buildpack, overwriting into list of buildpacks if neccessary
```

Answer (score 4):

Running `heroku config:unset` and `heroku buildpacks:remove` did not work for me. However, simply running `heroku buildpacks:clear` did restore everything to its default state. Then, on the next `git push heroku`, the appropriate buildpack is added on the fly.

Comment: Your approach may work on some cases but it isn't necessarily true. There are situations that require a little bit of attention in the process of choosing (and even ordering) buildpacks.